# How do I "one hot encode" a Tensorflow Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

Newby here... I loaded `TF` dataset as follows:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files)
dataset.map(extract_fn)
```

The dataset contains a "string column" with some values and I want to "one-hot" encode them. I could do that in the `extract_fn` record by record if I had indices and depth (I only have a String value as of now). However, is there a TF function that could do that for me? i.e.

- Count the number of distinct values
- Map each value to an index
- Create a one-hot encoded column for that

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def one_hot_any(a):
    # Save original shape
    s = tf.shape(a)
    # Find unique values
    values, idx = tf.unique(tf.reshape(a, [-1]))
    # One-hot encoding
    n = tf.size(values)
    a_1h_flat = tf.one_hot(idx, n)
    # Reshape to original shape
    a_1h = tf.reshape(a_1h_flat, tf.concat([s, [n]], axis=0))
    return a_1h, values

# Test
x = tf.constant([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'd'], ['c', 'd'], ['b', 'd']])
x_1h, x_vals = one_hot_any(x)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(*sess.run([x_1h, x_vals]), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. 0.]]

 [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0.]]]
[b'a' b'b' b'd' b'c']
```

The problem, though, is that different inputs will produce inconsistent outputs, with different value orders or even different one-hot depth, so I'm not sure if it is really useful.